Can low voltage recessed LED lights be sealed with normal spray foam?
From my research, recessed lights should not be sealed with spray foam (and some should not even be in contact with insulation). How about low power LED lights that come with external power supply?
I have tons of these, as viewed from my attic:

They leak like crazy. If I step in and don't turn on the light, the circle around each glows.
They are connected to line voltage via a black metal box which I believe is a rectifier/power supply and the actual recessed light is connected via the thin white cable as shown.
Can I just spray the perimeter with spray foam to air seal it?
Based on the picture, it seems to be Intertek / Commercial Electric Ultra Slim CCT Canless Recessed LED light. According to this link, it is "IC (Insulation Contact) Rated".

What do they leak?

@Huesmann they leak warm air. According to https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=v-YWiPXChrQ, recessed rights can have a substantial impact on CFMs. I haven’t measured but since I can see the light shining through the cracks I think this is a major air leak

So this is an attic space, then?  Do you have lights in your attic that would cause glow?  It looks like no insulation, which may be at least as big a problem as air leaks.

@Huesmann yes, attic. It is insulated, I just removed the batting for the picture. I am not sure what you mean with light in the attics that cause glow; Yes there is a light in the attic but I turned it off and I can clearly see the light from the room below shining through the cracks between the light and the ceiling. All I am saying is there are huge gaps from conditioned space (=kitchen room below) to unconditioned space (=attic) that I need to seal.

Ah, I misunderstood the direction of the glow.  I mean, assuming these guys are IC rated, I'd just stuff some batting into the gaps.

Do you see light and feel air flow leaking around the lights when the insulation is in place? If not, then there's nothing to worry about because the insulation is doing its job. If you only feel air movement when there's no insulation there, well, what did you expect?

@FreeMan If I put a batting on top of it, sure I wouldn't see much light. Insulation's job is preventing heat conduction. Sealing's job is preventing air leakage. So, independent of any insulation, I expect proper sealing which prevents air to flow.

The standard is to put a flowerpot (without hole) on top of the downlight.
It reserves an air space in the insulation so the downlight gets a bit of cooling, and you can push the wire and connector in this space too. The flowerpot can be sealed against the attic floor with anything that will seal: plaster, spray foam, etc.
For low power LED lights I'd use a ceramic saucer: it is very cheap, and if you seal it, you can still change the LED downlight when it stops working. And when you pull the downlight out to replace it, all the insulation doesn't fall on your face. It costs about $2.


You can create a seal between the light's trim ring and the ceiling using museum putty or a similar material. Drop the light out of the ceiling, run a bead of the putty around the top of the trim ring large enough to seal the gap and press the fixture back into place.
The resulting seal will block drafts and allow for a little movement, but it will also allow you to replace a fixture when the time comes without damaging the ceiling. Using adhesive caulk will make replacement a messier chore.

So, consider if the lights need to radiate heat to stay cool.
Then what about putting a "hat" over the lamp and then sealing around that? Volume and heat come to mind again.
The hat will allow the cable and switch etc to be easily accessed as well.

I assume you mean these? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Tenmat-Recessed-Light-Cover-FF130E/204286308 ? I found these but the reason I was asking here is twofold: (1) Each of these is 20$ and that adds up to hundreds of dollars (2) they disturb the continuity of the insulation and can cause a thermal bridge (3) They are specifically for “old” recessed lights. My lights in question are just 9W LED and specifically rated for “Insulation Contact”. So I can confidently bury them under my insulation battings. But I am not sure about spray foam.
